# layout in ionic 3 using grid and flex

Tags: html, css, ionic3

I have 3 rows in my layout(20% 60% 20%) and I want to insert images and some text in that layout and I have done. but I want to know what I have done is correct or not?

I should use flexbox or not in this case?

I tried this in ionic 3 but I don know whether it is correct or not
please help me with this
    ionic html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="myrow">
      <ion-col class="first mycol">
        <!-- images in col -->
        <ion-row>
          <div class="firstrh">
          <ion-col col-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4>
              <img src="../../assets/imgs/3.jfif">
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4>
              <img src="../../assets/imgs/4.jfif">
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4>
              <img src="../../assets/imgs/5.jfif">
          </ion-col>
        </div>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col> 
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="myrow">
      <ion-col col-4 class="second border  mycol">
        <!-- first col -->
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <p>Something that has to be written here</p>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <p>Something that has to be written here</p>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <p>Something that has to be written here</p>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-8 class="border  mycol">
        <!-- second col -->
        <ion-row>
          <div class="thirdrh">
          <ion-col col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4>
            <img src="../../assets/imgs/1.jfif">
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4>
              <img src="../../assets/imgs/2.jfif">
          </ion-col>
        </div>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="myrow">
      <ion-col class="third">

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>


ionic css:
page-responsive {
    width:100vh;
    height:100vh;
    .scroll-content{
    padding:0!important;
    margin:0;
    }
    border:1px solid blue;
    .myrow{
        border:1px solid red;
        position: relative;
    }
    .mycol{
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    .firstrh{
        height:20vh!important;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow:row wrap;
        img{
            width:100%;
            height:18vh;
        }
    }
    .thirdrh{
        height:60vh!important;
        display: flex;
        overflow:hidden;
        img{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
    }
    ion-col.first{
        height:20vh;
        width:100%;
    }
    ion-col.second{
        height:60vh;
        width:100%;
    }
    ion-col.third{
        height:20vh;
        width:100%;
    }
    .border{
        border:1px solid gray;
    }

}
```

layout check

Comment: add a snippet..

Answer (score 0):

[The Ionic 3 Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#grid) has a detailed explanation concerning the *Grid* layout feature: "The grid system is made of a 12 columns, and each ion-col can be sized by setting the col- attribute."

If you say that you have three **rows** (20%, 60%, 20%), do you probably mean **columns**? In the latter case, you cannot exactly achieve your required percentages because the 12 column layout of Ionic 3 provides no column separation where the center column is three times as wide as the left and right. Thus, you should either use your own layout styling (e. g. with FlexBox, as you mentioned) or accept the center column to be slightly thinner:

```html
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-3>This column will take 3 columns (=25%)</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>This column will take 6 columns (=50%)</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3>This column will take 3 columns (=25%)</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: yeah i am aware of 12 columns in one row.my question is i want 3 rows and first row should be of 20vh , second 60vh and third 20vh.in each row i want to display image that shoul be properly fix with in that row.how do i acieve that

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `vh` (= viewport **height**) as a measure for **rows**? Do you need the rows to be `20vh`/ `60vh` / `20vh` in width or height?

Comment: My question was **which dimension** you want to style with `vh' - horizontal (width) or vertical (height)?

Comment: its vertical height

Comment: In that case, you could introduce a CSS rule `ion-grid { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }` and attach some new classes to your rows, e. g. `<ion-row class="myrow short">` and `<ion-row class="myrow long">` with CSS rules `ion-row.short { height: 20vh; }` and `ion-row.long { height: 60vh; }`.

Comment: in my case i have assigned vh to col, i.e, <ion-row><ion-col short></ion-col><ion-row><ion-col long></ion-col></ion-row><ion-row><ion-col short></ion-col></ion-row> and css : ion-col.long{  height: 60vh; } ion-col.short{  height: 20vh; } what if i use this?